# Where is the command line located?

Tags: windows, command

This is what I need to do...
Run your app from the command line

Build the project from the command line. The output APK for the app module is located in app/build/outputs/apk/.
Make sure the Android SDK platform-tools/ directory is included in your PATH environment variable.
Execute this command:
adb install app/build/outputs/MyFirstApp-debug.apk
On the emulator, locate MyFirstApp and open it.

I don't know where to find it, in order to do it?
Help...

Comment: What environment are you using? Windows? KDE? GNOME? ...?

Comment: Windows 7 professional.

Comment: Any of: Start | Command Prompt -or- Start | Run | cmd -or- Win+R | cmd

Comment: Will have a look... thanks!